# IWA authentication alternative on linux

Tags: rhel, authentication, active-directory

Im having a windows server configured with an adfs, which is used as Idp with saml in keycloak for my application, then I'm using adfs Device authentication, so I can login to my apps using my session credentials, on windows it works fine, I want to do the same from a Linux rhel 8 workstation, what is the best approach to do that?
I already configured sssd and Pam so I can login with ad users on GUI but I'm missing the part to map the session credentials to adfs.